# invalid use of non-static data member ‘lasd::BinaryTreeVec<int>::treeVec’

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, static

I'm implementing a Binary Tree using a Vector that I've previously defined. The Binary Tree has a struct Node inside and it's like it's not possible to get access to the Vector defined inside Binary Tree class from my Node functions.

So this is the Binary Tree :

```
template <typename Data>
class BinaryTreeVec : public BinaryTree<Data>{ 
private:

protected:
    using BinaryTree<Data>::size;
    ulong height = 0;

public:
    using typename BinaryTree<Data>::Node;

    struct NodeVec : public Node{ 
    private:

    protected:
        using Node::value;
        ulong left;
        ulong right;
        ulong index;
        ulong height;
        bool isValid = false;

    public:
        friend class BinaryTreeVec<Data>;

        ....


        bool HasLeftChild() const noexcept override; // Override Node member
        bool HasRightChild() const noexcept override; // Override Node member

        ....
    }

    ....

protected:
    Vector<struct NodeVec> treeVec;
}
```

Everything works fine until I call the HasLeftChild() functions where I get 
error: invalid use of non-static data member ‘lasd::BinaryTreeVec::treeVec’.
My professor suggests me that using a reference would be the best option to solve the problem, so tried to declare a reference to **treeVec** so that I could use it inside NodeVec but it was completely useless.

```
template <typename Data>
bool BinaryTreeVec<Data>::NodeVec::HasLeftChild() const noexcept{
    if( 2 * index + 1 < treeVec.Size())
        return ( treeVec[2 * index + 1].flag == true );

    return false; 
}
```

I got compiler error every time I use **treeVec** in the HasLeftChild() function up here.

Comment: 'It was completely useless' Probably you just did it wrong, but I guess we'll never know. Using a reference would be one solution, but there are others. The normal method is for your node class to have pointers to the child nodes. I guess there's some reason you haven't gone with that as it's the easiest option. Another option would be to pass the tree vector into HasLeftChild as a parameter.

Comment: how could I solve it with a reference?

Comment: Well, put a reference (to the tree I guess) into your Node class, initialise it in the Node constructor, use it in HasLeftChild.

Comment: Would it be possible to have a reference to **treeVec** inside Node? so that Node knows  the Vector it is in?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what your professor is suggesting (I assume). I mean I don't think it's particularly brilliant design, but I can't think what else he meant.

Comment: Well ... I tried several times but I haven't come up with a solution. So I tried to creating a reference to **treeVec** doing  Vector<struct NodeVec> &ref = treeVec but it doesn't work. How can I create a reference inside the Node to the class BinaryTreeVec, so to the object Node is in  or to treeVec in a proper way? thanks again

Comment: See answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to add a treeVec reference to your node class

```
struct NodeVec : public Node {
protected:
    ...
    Vector<NodeVec>& treeVec;
public:
    NodeVec(Vector<NodeVec>& tv) : treeVec(tv) {}
    ...
};
```

I've created a new constructor to bind the reference. I am assuming that you don't already have a constructor, but if you do then you'll have to add the above code to your existing constructor instead.

And of course you will need to change your existing code wherever you make a Node to pass in the new treevec parameter.